# Can golang import package from private subversion repository?

Tags: git, svn, go

As we know golang support import package from famous code hosted sites, such as github,google code and so on, but what I would like to figure out is whether golang support import package from my private subversion/git repository? It would become easier to share some common package among projects if golang support this.

an ideal example:

```
package main

import "192.168.12.13/trunk/share/foolib"

func main() {
   ....
   foolib.xxxx...
}
```

Comment: it should work.. See [here](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#Remote_import_path_syntax)

Answer (score 6):

yes, you can import code from private repositories, run `go help importpath` for instructions.

this is, however, a two phase approach: first get the code, than compile it into your project.

your example suggests that you want to import remote code (so, a one phase process essentially), I doubt that is possible

Comment: It works! first phase: go get 192.168.12.13/trunk/share/foolib.svn, second phase: import foolib "192.168.12.13/trunk/share/foolib.svn" in go source file.

Comment: @Tony Bai you should accept this as the answer then

Answer (score 2):

If it's a private repository, you're almost certainly better off managing this manually.

For subversion use a subversion external; for git use a submodule, etc.

```
go get ...
```

Is a helpful tool, but you'll probably run into difficulty once you start using closed signed internal repositories; since most non-stupid source control already supports this type of 'submodule' like functionality, you're probably better off using the facilities of whatever source control you use and importing your custom submodules into your 'src' directory, and then, as above, importing using:

```
import mylib "modules/xxx/trunk/src/blah"
```

...rather than trying to force go get to do all the things all of the time.